# Parse an integer (and *only* an integer) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, parsing, converters

Prompt as it is possible to translate a string to number so that only any variant except for the integer produced an error.

```
func('17') = 17;
func('17.25') = NaN
func(' 17') = NaN
func('17test') = NaN
func('') = NaN
func('1e2') = NaN
func('0x12') = NaN
```

**ParseInt** does not work, because it does not work correctly.

```
ParseInt('17') = 17;
ParseInt('17.25') = 17 // incorrect
ParseInt(' 17') = NaN
ParseInt('17test') = 17 // incorrect
ParseInt('') = NaN
ParseInt('1e2') = 1 // incorrect
```

And most importantly: for the function to work in IE, Chrome and other browsers!!!

Comment: Number() will get you close, but do you want to discard decimal places or do you really want to reject them as NaN?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) and the ternary operator to reject all strings containing non-digits:

```js
function intOrNaN (x) {
  return /^\d+$/.test(x) ? +x : NaN
}

console.log([
  '17', //=> 17
  '17.25', //=> NaN
  ' 17', //=> NaN
  '17test', //=> NaN
  '', //=> NaN
  '1e2', //=> NaN
  '0x12' //=> NaN
].map(intOrNaN))
```

Comment: Why did you add + before x?

Comment: @WessamElMahdy The unary + operator casts the value of x to a number (hence strings of digits are reinterpreted as a base-10 numeric literal)

Answer (score 3):

This would satisfy all your tests:

```
function func (str) {
  var int = parseInt(str, 10);
  return str == str.trim() && str == int ? int : NaN
}
```